# Location of first cell in an excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I use Excel tables a lot. It makes it possible to have multiple tables in one worksheet. But I have got into a problem in VBA which I do not know how to solve.

Let us say that I have a table called "tbl" in my spreadsheet. It contains the following data:

```
id value
1  1000
1  2000
2  3000
2  4000
```

I have the following code which works:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl").DataBodyRange
    arr = rng.Value
End Sub
```

This code will put the whole table into `arr`. But there are situations where I only want some rows in the table. Let us say that I want row 4 and 5 i.e:

```
2  3000
2  4000
```

The following code will do the trick:

```
arr = Range("A4:B5")
```

But there are cases where I have many tables located in different places in my spreadsheet. Therefore I need to work out where the first cell in the table is located (upper left). If it is located in K1, I need to get both the column and the row (K and 1).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to actually FIND the cell first, say the one below a specific table header?  You can use the Cell address as shown below once you find it, if you already know it then all the merrier.  In your example above: Dim onerow As double // onerow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("K1").Row // same for column except .column // easier if you dim a worksheet and assign the worksheet once ex. with Set fossWS =  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheetname") // then its onecol = fossWS.Range("K1").Column  It's all down below using address and getting the row/col

Comment: I suppose my comment above it do you have to find the location of "ID" or "value" to target the left corner of your data range and then find the data table boundary lower right corner?  Are the tables always the same size and in the same location?  Those are trickier asks for multiple tables, multiple worksheets, multiple workbooks . . . .

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code We (Scott and I) interpreted the question as the OP knows the **name** of the table (e.g. "tbl") and which worksheet it is on, but doesn't know where that table is located within the worksheet.  So, given just a table name (and the knowledge that it is on the active worksheet), how can specific rows of data from that table be extracted?

Comment: gotcha, you 2 are always one step ahead of me . . . . Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Cells():

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr() As Variant
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl").DataBodyRange
arr = ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Cells(3, 1), rng.Cells(4, 2)).Value    
End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to ask why you deleted your answer.  It works. @YowE3K

Comment: I deleted my answer because it is effectively the same as yours - and I was only posting because I had missed the `rng.Cells` part of your answer, so was thinking you were just getting the raw sheet cells :D  (Plus I was thinking the question asked how to get the first two rows, not the 3rd and 4th row.)

Comment: Well, undelete yours as it is a viable alternative.  I prefer cells as it works better in my head, but the OP may prefer your method.

Comment: I like Cells, .address, and .row / .column

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the third and fourth data rows (i.e. fourth and fifth rows if you count the heading row), you could use

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl").DataBodyRange
    arr = rng.Rows("3:4").Value
    'or
    arr = rng.Range("A3:B4").Value
End Sub
```

Because the `Rows` and `Range` properties are being applied to the `rng` object, the references (`"3:4"` and `"A3:B4"`) are relative to the start of the `rng` object.

So you could also get the worksheet address of the first cell in `rng` by using `rng.Range("A1").Address` (or `rng.Cells(1, 1).Address`), or you can get the first cell's worksheet row and column by just using `rng.Row` and `rng.Column` respectively (they both default to returning the value for the first cell).

Comment: As stated in my comments,  The fact that you can use A1 reference in a table that does not start in the actual A1 cell, just makes my brain hurt.  But I can wrap my feeble mind around a grid location, and as such the use of cells makes sense.

Comment: @ScottCraner To be perfectly honest, I prefer `Cells` myself so, although my `Rows("3:4")` makes sense to me, my `Range("A3:B4")` makes my brain hurt too - it is too confusing to me to think in terms of worksheet A1 notation when it isn't a worksheet :D

Comment: I like Cells, .address, and .row / .column

Answer (score 1):

The first cell in a table has some unique properties:

-It is not empty

-The cell above it is null

-The cell to the left of it is null

-The cell below it is not null

Using these properties you can do something like:

1) Loop over every cell

2) If that cell has the above properties, then it is a "top left" cell

3) Do whatever with that table

Comment: branx is looking for the corner of the table.  Not clear from OP whether they know the table positions or must find them, whether the size of the table may change (defining the lower right cell to complete the range).  Good thinking concept for today.